# Update GRUB with encrypted LVM on second volume/drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, encryption, lvm

On one machine I have an encrypted LUKS container around an LVM on `/dev/sda` that I can boot into. On the same machine is a second drive with an encrypted LUKS container around an LVM on `/dev/sdb` (that GRUB from `/dev/sda` doesn't see at the moment).

Ideally, I would like to have GRUB from `/dev/sda` ask if I would like to load Ubuntu `/dev/sda` or Ubuntu `/dev/sdb`.

How can I update GRUB located on `/dev/sda` so that it offers the two `/boot`s (one on `/dev/sda` and one on `/dev/sdb`) as startup options?

- `sudo update-grub` does not add the `/dev/sdb` option to the startup option list.
- Boot-Repair also does not automatically do what I want.